# HTML select, previously selected value in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have select option in HTML and I don't know how to put previosly selected value after reload.

```
<select ng-init="city_id = city_id" name="region" id="region" ng-model="city_id" >
    <option value="-1"  selected="selected">Select area</option>
    <option ng-repeat="city in cities" value="{{city.id}}" ng-class="{ 'bold' : city.capital == 1 }">{{ city.name }}</option>
</select>
```

I used controller and created $scope.city_id and it has a value. But select still has default value.

Select area item is necessary for me because i can't modify json data to add this optio in cotroller.

Solution:

```
<option ng-selected="city_id == city.id" ng-repeat="city in cities" ...
```

Comment: take a look at [ng-storage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-selected` for select option

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is that the controller is destroyed you may want store it in a value, I.e. angular.module ('myApp').value ('name',value)